# Зафиксировать сумму на момент итерации

Tags: python, матрицы

Короче говоря я новичок в кодинге на питоне и вообще, столкнулся с задачей по матрице, и не совсем понимаю, как правильно в моем коде записать сумму соседних элементов со всех сторон на текущей позиции, где происходит на данный момент итерация цикла.

Вот код:

```
matrix = [[int(x) for x in input().split()]]
inside_matrix = input()
final_matrix = []
while inside_matrix != 'end':
    matrix.append([int(i) for i in inside_matrix.split()])
    inside_matrix = input()
if len(matrix) < 2:
    print((matrix[0][0]) * 4)
else:
    for i in range(0, len(matrix)):
        for j in range(0, len(matrix)):
            if matrix[i][j] == matrix[0][0]:
                #final_matrix[i][j] = ((matrix[-1][j]) + (matrix[i][-1]) + (matrix[i + 1][j]) + (matrix[i][j + 1]))
                final_matrix.append((matrix[-1][j]) + (matrix[i][-1]) + (matrix[i + 1][j]) + (matrix[i][j + 1]))
            elif matrix[i][j] == matrix[0][-1]:
                #final_matrix[i][j] = (matrix[-1][j]) + (matrix[i][j - 1]) + (matrix[i + 1][j]) + (matrix[i][0])
                final_matrix.append((matrix[-1][j]) + (matrix[i][j - 1]) + (matrix[i + 1][j]) + (matrix[i][0]))
            elif matrix[i][j] == matrix[i][-1]:
                #final_matrix[i][j] = (matrix[i - 1][j]) + (matrix[i][j - 1]) + (matrix[i + 1][j]) + (matrix[i][0])
                final_matrix.append((matrix[i - 1][j]) + (matrix[i][j - 1]) + (matrix[i + 1][j]) + (matrix[i][0]))
            elif matrix[i][j] == matrix[-1][0]:
                #final_matrix[i][j] = (matrix[i - 1][j]) + (matrix[i][-1]) + (matrix[0][j]) + (matrix[i][j + 1])
                final_matrix.append((matrix[i - 1][j]) + (matrix[i][-1]) + (matrix[0][j]) + (matrix[i][j + 1]))
            elif matrix[i][j] == matrix[-1][j]:
                #final_matrix[i][j] = (matrix[i - 1][j]) + (matrix[i][j - 1]) + (matrix[0][j]) + (matrix[i][j + 1])
                final_matrix.append((matrix[i - 1][j]) + (matrix[i][j - 1]) + (matrix[0][j]) + (matrix[i][j + 1]))
            elif matrix[i][j] == matrix[-1][-1]:
                #final_matrix[i][j] = (matrix[i - 1][j]) + (matrix[i][j - 1]) + (matrix[0][j]) + (matrix[i][0])
                final_matrix.append((matrix[i - 1][j]) + (matrix[i][j - 1]) + (matrix[0][j]) + (matrix[i][0]))
            else:
                #final_matrix[i][j] = (matrix[i - 1][j]) + (matrix[i][j - 1]) + (matrix[i + 1][j]) + (matrix[i][j + 1])
                final_matrix.append((matrix[i - 1][j]) + (matrix[i][j - 1]) + (matrix[i + 1][j]) + (matrix[i][j + 1]))
        #print(*final_matrix[i])
print(*final_matrix)
```

Для примера есть инпут тестовой выборки, и аутпут выборки:

Инпут:

```
9 5 3
0 7 -1
-5 2 9
end
```

Аутпут:

```
3 21 22
10 6 19
20 16 -1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Питон отлично манипулирует списками. Основная проблема, как из суммы исключить 'целевой' элемент.

```
rows = (
(9, 5, 3),
(0, 7, -1),
(-5, 2, 9)
)

columns = list(zip(*rows))

for x, row in enumerate(rows):
    row_sum = (sum([*row, *col]) - 2 * col[x] for col in columns)
    print(' '.join(map(str, row_sum)))
```